# Give three examples of complex numbers where z = -z

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm currently learning for an algebra exam and I have some examples of questions from few last years. And I can't find a solution to this one:

> Give three examples of complex numbers where z = -z

The only complex number I can think of is 0. Because it is a complex number, isn't it? Like 0 + 0i.

What two other complex numbers can be given as examples?

Edit: Well, I'm pretty sure it's z = -z. I have only this low-resolution picture, but you can see it in the first task: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BhNn.jpg. Yeah, I know it's all in Polish, but you have to believe me it says to find three examples.

Edit 2: Okay, now I see that it might actually say $\bar{z} = -z$.

Comment: $0$ is indeed the only complex number $z$ for which $z=-z$.  Is it possible that you read $1/z = -z$?  In that case there would be two of them. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: ... or maybe $z=-\bar z$?

Comment: I think you are right. $0$ should be the only solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I have only this low-resolution picture and I'm pretty sure it says z = -z, please take a look (it's in the first task): http://i.imgur.com/2EuugPZ.jpg And it's all in Polish, so you have to believe me it says about three examples.

Comment: Looks like it might be $\bar{z} = -z$.

Comment: Oh... now I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is actually $\bar{z} = -z$, then writing $z = a + bi$ for real $a, b$, we have

$$a - bi = -a - bi$$

Hence $a = 0$ and $b$ can take on any value.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
z = -z
$$
then we can add $z$ to both sides of the equation, getting
$$
2z = 0
$$
and then we can divide both sides by $2$, getting
$$
z=0.
$$
My suspicion is that you've misread the question and it said something other than $z=-z$.